# Passing the exam - spam?

Tags: discussion

Many of you might have seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1310370/how-many-marks-do-i-need-to-pass-my-class).

I vaguely remember the user Chelsea, who was showered with downvotes (I am not sure if it was for asking "marks I need to pass the exam"-like question, I remember such question being asked during the time I encountered that username if I remember correctly). Is there anyway to check it?

**Edit:** I am not saying they are off-topic. They seem rational and on topic question, minus that the user doesn't show that they have done anything about it (than to score low marks) or it sounds like an input to a good mark calculator with AI.

Comment: Doesn't look like spam to me. The one that was received so badly, had a title that ticked some off; like: "I HATE MATH SO MUCH BUT I NEED A SOLUTION" or some such thing. Moderators likely could check, but it is not quite clear to me what for. That is to me your question seems like idle curiosity (which is fine, but if it is not you might want to clarify the intent).

Comment: @quid, clearly this one doesn't look like spam - but recurrence in same format is what's making me doubt! I can't locate the old post, probably got deleted!

Comment: "Spam" [has a precise definition](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work/58035#58035): "A post should be marked as spam ONLY when it contains an unsolicited advertisement.". Whatever you do, please do not flag the posts mentioned in the OP as spam (unless they really contain an ad), because it only confuses the automatic processes in place to detect actual spam.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, I did not report spam! There's no reason to! But if only such posts are spam, what about the cases I expressed in question (I am not saying this one is): when someone keeps asking same question with different numbers, aiming to bloat up number of questions? In general sense, (probably outside SE), that's also counted as spam, isn't it? Like comments on blog saying "I loved your post, would love to see more of such content" which keep repeating - looks legit, but in real is a spam!

Comment: This kind of content may be unwanted, but it's not spam by the definitions used by the website -- I'm just warning you that if you decide to flag such behavior, don't use the flag "spam". If there's a valid close reason, flag to close, if it's "very low quality" you can flag as that, if a comment is too chatty/whatever you can also flag it, in last resort you can flag for mod attention if this is exceptionally bad content but the usual mechanisms cannot apply.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation.

This is the description of the spam flag. It shouldn't be used for anything else.

If a post is about mathematics and not about getting you to visit some website, buy a product or call some phone number, it is not spam. No matter how bad the question is, spam flagging is the wrong way to deal with it.

Spam flags can have rather drastic consequences. A successful spam flag carries a -100 reputation penalty. Enough spam flags will block any low-reputation user from the same network.

The spam defense system is also used against trolls that deliberately post crap on the site or try to abuse the system in some way. But that is something the moderators can decide, they have a better overview over the actions of such trolls.